# Converting An Audio Jack from Line Out to Line In

Tags: audio-recording

I would like to do a multi track audio recording at home using a software like audacity. In my old PC which is no longer working [:(] I used to have a provision to convert line-out i.e. the  speaker out jack also as a line-in jack using a software. I would like to do the same with my new HP laptop. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that ability is determined by the audio card and drivers. If the card doesn't support it, changing the software won't help. I would make sure you have the latest drivers for that card and then check under your audio settings.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the answer is no.  You can permanently damage your sound card if you attempt to run a signal into the output jack.  Unless the hardware specifically allows for this, I would not attempt it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go out and buy a USB audio interface ([UCA202](http://www.behringer.com/EN/Products/UCA202.aspx) for example or [this](http://www.m-audio.com/products/en_us/FastTrack.html) or maybe [this](http://www.presonus.com/products/detail.aspx?productid=53))